# File bundle has been rejected. Package ID is required for all .bar Blackberry

Tags: release, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10, blackberry-world

I'm loading a realease .zip file with two .bar files: App_2.2.0.5.bar for Playbook and App_1.0.4.11.bar BB10 OS.
When I upload the file it reject the last one I packaged (I tried for many times)

> "File bundle has been rejected. Package ID is required for all .bar
>   file. If this is an upgrade, Package ID must match Package ID in
>   original file bundle."

And what is the device name of Playbook to be auto assigned?

I'm using Webworks SDK 2.2.0.5 for Playbook and 1.0.4.11 for BB10 OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

First I compile my App with Webworks SDK 2.2.0.5 for Playbook with an ID of Name and I get a hashed ID from this compilation.
Second I compile my App with SDK 1.0.4.11 for BB10 with the ID that I got from the first compilation (inside the MANIFEST.MF file of the package)

=>The result is I have two packages for different platforms with the same Package ID

Comment: Please accept your own solution.  Note, you can change the ID inside your BB10 manifest to match that of your PlayBook version.